# webjobs in azure for a springBatch project

Tags: java, azure, spring-batch, azure-webjobs

I am new in azure and trying to deploy  my spring Batch project as a web jobs in azure.Can somebody help me with the process or changes require to do in my spring batch project before add in webjobs as a jar .

I have tried with  export jar and  add  that jar as webjob in azure service but its not working for me .
and also help me with how can i export a jar file from my spring Batch proeject

Answer (score 0):

To create an executable jar, the jar must have a MANIFEST.MF class that points to the main class. I guess azure webjobs will try to execute the main class without arguments, so you cannot use `org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner` directly.

So you'll need to write a custom main class, something like:

```
public class ApplicationMain {


  public static void main(String[] args) {
            
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
    app.setWebEnvironment(false);
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = app.run(args);
    JobLauncher jobLauncher = ctx.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
        .add...
        .toJobParameters();  
        
    jobLauncher.run(ctx.getBean("...",  Job.class), jobParameters);  

    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

In your MANIFEST.MF file, you will then need:

```
Main-Class: com.something.ApplicationMain
```

If that's not working for you, please specify additional details in your question.

Comment: Thanks for reply but what i am doing is i have a spring batch project i am creating a jar ,and trying to add that jar in webjob in azure but in my main call i am using one annotation @ImportResource("classpath:master-slave.xml") which contain configuration xml file ,but while running web job i am getting an error of Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [master-slave.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist -- master-slave.xml file i kept in src/main/resource folder any idea how can i resolve this . Thanks

Comment: What happens if you run it locally with 'java -jar application.jar'? If that fails as well, you need to look at your build. Do you use maven? Gradle?